# Please explain this Octave Error Code: op1 is 1x12, op2 is 1x3

Tags: octave

[image]

Code:

```
function result = assess_polynomial_n(y,n)

    [coeff, t, pred_accum] = fit_data(y, n);
    [avg, std_dev] = compute_error(coeff,y);
    [coeff1, t, pred_accum1] = fit_data(y, n+1);
    [avg1, std_dev1] = compute_error(coeff1,y);
    if avg1>avg
        result = n;
    elseif avg<0.1 && std_dev<0.1
        result = n;   
    elseif pred_accum1.*(1)<0.0001
        result = n;
    else
        result = 0;
    end
end
```

```
***Error***
error: compute_error: operator -: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x12, op2 is 1x3)
error: called from
    compute_error at line 11 column 17
    assess_polynomial_n at line 19 column 18
    __tester__.octave at line 38 column 1
```

Does anyone know why I could be getting this error? We're supposed to be working in MATLAB but pasting our code into Moodle which uses Octave if that clears anything up.

I also will post the functions I'm calling for reference since the error is occurring in Compute_Error. This is a part of an overall project where I was to define the functions I'm calling before creating assess_polynomial_n.

```
function [coeff, t, pred_accum] = fit_data(y, n)
    len = length(y);
    t = 10*[0:len-1];
    coeff = polyfit(t, y, n);
    pred_accum = polyval(coeff, t);
end

function [avg std_dev] = compute_error(x,y)
    s=[];
    for i=1:length(x)
        error=abs(x(i)-y(i));
        s=[s,error];
    end
    avg = mean(s);
    std_dev = std(s);
end
```

Comment: 1: It’s Octave, not MATLAB. 2: please copy-paste the full error message into the question. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). 3: Please take care to properly format your code.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the site, and panicking as this is for a project. I hope the edits are more clear. Also we are using MATLAB as our code but pasting into Moodle which uses Octave, for clarification.

Comment: `compute_error` is not a standard function, and not given here. The error happens inside that function. Likely you’re passing inputs of wrong size, but we can’t tell you how to use this function we don’t know anything about.

Comment: yes, please include the `compute_error` function if you want us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line of code:
`[avg1, std_dev1] = compute_error(coeff1,y);`

You are trying to compute the error between the original data and the *coefficients* of the fitted polynomial. It doesn't make sense, right?

Instead, you should compute the error between the original data and the *fitted* data, which is the polynomial's output at each `t` value. The correct code would be:
`[avg1, std_dev1] = compute_error(pred_accum1,y);`